# LDAP Connections are not closed when using LdapTemplate

Tags: java, jndi, spring-ldap

After shutting down Tomcat we saw a lot of errors regarding possible memory leak because Tomcat has failed to stop a thread. 
According to Tomcat we had ~2600 daemon threads which are waiting in com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.pauseReader.

We are using LdapTemplate to read data from LDAP. LdapTemplate is created each time we need to read data from LDAP. From the documentation I see that all the resources are released by LdapTemplate after search ends.
We have not enabled pooling for LdapTemplate and the default is false.

After debugging it looks that the threads which are created for Connection are not destroyed immediately after search ends but some of the threads are destroyed eventually.

Any idea why we will have so many daemon threads waiting on com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.pauseReader?

We are using spring-ldap 2.0.2.RELEASE.

Sample code on how we are creating LdapTemplate before performing the search:

```
LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
SimpleAuthenticationSource authenticationSource = new SimpleAuthenticationSource(userDn, password);
contextSource.setAuthenticationSource(authenticationSource);
LdapTemplate ldapTemplate = new LdapTemplate(contextSource);
ldapTemplate.setIgnorePartialResultException(true);
```

Update:
 After settings pooled to true the connections are released ok.

```
ldapContextSource.setPooled(true);
```

The issue is that we cannot use pooling. I still don't understand why when not using pool the Connections are not released properly.

Comment: Can you put an example of how are you using LdapTemplate, Spring version and that kind of things, it can be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you're not using connection pooling, but that may well solve the problem you're seeing with runaway threads.

[Take a look here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/reference/#pooling) at how to configure LDAP connection pooling via Spring XML configuration with `PoolingContextSource`.  [Here is another example](https://github.com/larryfinkelstein/play-java-springldap/blob/b86a239af25767904ccf71e0555f3f55975ecf7c/app/configs/LdapConfig.java) of how to enable connection pooling using annotation-based configuration.

Note the documentation mentions specifically to enable pooling in Spring LDAP, and not the JNDI LDAP provider in the JDK via the `"com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool"` property.

For reference, here is a similar issue from 2013 where it appears enabling connection pooling was able to reduce the number of threads: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/2397

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot use pool as each time the credentials may differ so connections cannot be reused. In addition we are using GSSAPI for authentication and TLS so according to documentation connection pool will not work properly.
I saw the issue from 2013 but I'm not sure I understand why pool helped. Shouldn't LdapTemplate close all resources including Connection after the search?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of debugging the issue was that in one of the queries we retrieved the context without closing it:

```
ldapTemplate.getContextSource().getReadOnlyContext().getNameInNamespace()
```

And we didn't close the context after usage.

Closing the context solved the issue, no threads are in waiting status after the fix.